# NSMutableArray in CDVInvokedUrlCommand Crashing app

Tags: objective-c, cordova

Alright, so in Cordova 2.1 CDVInvokedUrlCommand.m there's a function -(void)legacyArguments that has some purpose with URLs.  My problem is that code in Cordova calls legacyArguments when a variable _arguments is set to nil, and crashes the app.  Try to check if _arguments == nil always returns false (whether it is nil or if it has values) and [_arguments count] crashes the app as well.

The line that crashes the app is...

```
NSMutableArray* newArguments = [NSMutableArray arrayWithArray:_arguments];
```

To fix it for now, I just need to check to make sure _arguments isn't nil, but I can't find a reliable way of doing so.  Perhaps there's a 'safe' way to make the above call or an alternate way to check _arguments that won't crash the app if it's nil?

EDIT: Since it was requested...

```
-[__NSCFConstantString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ee98
2012-09-20 11:04:59.825 EESEmployee[50307:15b03] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFConstantString count]: unrecognized selector sent to instance 0x8ee98'
*** First throw call stack:
(0xf4c012 0x262de7e 0xfd74bd 0xf3bbbc 0xf3b94e 0x1ad30 0x66dcd 0x665fe 0x669d9 0x26416b0 0x13e0035 0xecff3f 0xecf96f 0xef2734 0xef1f44 0xef1e1b 0x314a7e3 0x314a668 0xd165c 0x2ce6 0x2c15)
libc++abi.dylib: terminate called throwing an exception
```

Comment: "_arguments == nil always returns false (whether it is nil or if it has values)" - I have problems to believe that...

Comment: @MartinR: Believe what you want, a NSLog of _arguments would either return "" or "({stuff that was needed})" and both would return the same value when checking for nil (!= was always true, == was always false).   Also, this is working although I don't think I'm using isKindOfClass correctly...    [_arguments isKindOfClass:[NSMutableArray class]] && _arguments.count > 0

Comment: If `NSLog` shows "", then `_arguments` is probably an empty string, and that is `!= nil`. Perhaps I misunderstood the formulation in your question.

Comment: `-[__NSCFConstantString count]: unrecognized selector ...` says that `_arguments` is a string and not an array, as expected by `arrayWithArray:`.

Comment: The plugins thought they were sending a NSArray, but they were sending it to the wrong location.  I don't know where legacyArguments was getting the values for _arguments before, but I think you're right that it was receiving strings instead of arrays.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anyone else who gets this error, adding a check in CDVInvokedUrlCommand will allow you to continue debugging, but to 'fix' the problem you need to follow the instructions [here](https://github.com/apache/incubator-cordova-ios/blob/master/guides/Cordova%20Plugin%20Upgrade%20Guide.md) for upgrading the plugins for your Cordova/Phonegap project to 2.1

Personally, I'm going to leave the check in and have it display a message if it receives an illegal message (as opposed to just shutting down the whole app without giving any information).

Answer (score 0):

What is the usage of the new command vs the old?  I'm changing from...

```
-(void)getToken:(NSMutableArray *)arguments withDict:(NSMutableDictionary *)options
```

to this...

```
-(void)getToken:(CDVinvokedUrlCommand*)command
```

then setting a call back ID

```
self.callbackID = [arguments pop];
```

Since I'm not using arguments now, where is the callbackID?

Comment: I found this example and rewrote the plugin I found.  I had to change my headers and took out the self references.  Arguments is now [command.arguments objectAtIndex:0]

http://docs.phonegap.com/en/edge/guide_plugin-development_ios_index.md.html